# Adding JS to a specific URL

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I want to add some JS to a particular page.  In template.php, do I simply need to check request_path() in my preprocess_page() function in template.php?  Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the function you are looking for:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if(request_path() == 'your_path') {
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/yourjs.js');
  }

  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
}
```

Request path is an easier way to do this than the < Drupal 6.x method of reading the arg() string (ex. if arg(0) === 'node' && arg(1) === 'some node id')